# Can not find specific regular expression

Tags: regex

I can not find a regular expression that matches what I'm looking for.
I would like a regular expression that matches 15 consecutive characters (except space, exclamation point, comma, period). So far the expression is [^!\?.\s!,]{20}. But I do not want that match if in these 15 characters, 10 are identical.
So match with "jqshjsdfhjsdlfdjqlsmskjm" but not with "thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaank"
thank you

Comment: That's probably not what regex is up for. You would want to write a program and do that logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve something close to that: `(([^!\?.\s!,])(?!\1)){15}`. See the solution working [here](https://regex101.com/r/nsnTMF/1/).

This solution, however, has a setback: it fails when it finds patterns like `131` or `bab`. If even with this setback the solution works for you, then good. If not, then this is as far as regex goes. You'll have to work out that logic programatically.

**Disclaimer:** I'm out of time right now and will edit my answer later to include an explanation of the regex and the reason why it has a setback <sub>Although someone else could edit this answer and do it for me : )</sub> .